# GoDaddy hosting - How to solve Security Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, web-hosting

I have a problem with new hosting in GoDaddy. Just for testing I created very simple ASP .NET MVC application without database etc. But GoDaddy triggers Security Exception for line @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home") in my View. I don't understand the reason.

*(Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.)*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you use MVC 5 it is because [MVC 5 no longer supports partial trust](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/release-notes#knownissues). You can Add this line to web.config file in  section to grant full trust to code execution policy:

```
<system.Web>
...
    <trust level="Full"/>
...
</system.Web>
```

Comment: Answer is correct, but can you explain where in the web.config to add this?  `system.web` should be the root where it is added.  Here is the post that helped me https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkscy493(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Wasted several hours before finding this! This should be on GoDaddy's support site.

Comment: I had to do 2 things to get MVC app to work on GoDaddy's Plesk hosting

1) Uninstall nuget package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotnetCompilerPlatform

2) Set trust level to Full

Answer (score 8):

This can be done by two ways. 
1 - Add following code in WebConfig
`<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
</system.web>`

2- Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution in Visual Studio Find “DotNetCompilerPlatform” and uninstall it if present.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the solution. I had to change CAS trust level from medium to full in the settings.
https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8999/do-your-hosting-accounts-support-mvc4-and-mcv5-applications?countrysite=uk

Answer (score 0):

thanks friend, in my case I had to do the 3 things, change the web.config so...  trust level="Full" processRequestInApplicationTrust="false", 
, uninstall the "DotNetCompilerPlatform", and change the confidence level CAS on the server