# How to solve this error "System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed."?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have uploaded my website on GoDaddy server. It's first time I am uploading. But I am getting an error `System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.`

I have added

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

After I added above code it shows below error after I added. I don't know how to solve it. 
[image: Error Message]

Help me, thanks

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727678/godaddy-hosting-how-to-solve-security-exception